# What do $1 and $2 mean?

Tags: php, sql

What do the $1 and $2 in this line of code mean? Are they variables? But then how can they be used in a string?

```
$query = "select * from php_project.student where student_num=$1 and student_pass=$2";
```

EDIT: here are the next few lines:

```
        $stmt = pg_prepare($dbconn,"ps",$query);
        $result = pg_execute($dbconn,"ps",array($studentnum,$password));
        if (!$result){
            die("error in SQL query:".pg_last_error());
        }
```

Comment: those are the parameters need to be passed to the query

Comment: but they can be used directly in a string? like, string interpolation  in Ruby?

Comment: That's a very poor design decision - to use `$n` for a placeholder

Comment: @Chin is the query works?

Comment: Is `$query` passed into a `preg_*` function somewhere in the code?

Comment: @zerkms, it is the correct implementation per the documentation of the  official PostgreSQL client library in native PHP.  I agree, it is very strange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$1 and $2 are not variables.  They are being used as placeholders in the string.

In PHP $(number first) are not variables.  Try it yourself:

```
$1 = "bob";
>> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in PHP shell code on line 1
```

So "$1" is really a string that says "$1".

You could use str_replace, and get this:

```
PHP > echo str_replace("$1", "'Bob'", $query);
>> select * from php_project.student where student_num='Bob' and student_pass=$2
```

**UPDATE**

Per your update, pg_prepare actually says this:

> If any parameters are used, they are referred to in the query as $1,
> $2, etc.

So in your case, the `array($studentnum,$password)` basically replaces $1 with '$studentnum' and $2 with '$password' in your query, but it also escapes the values properly to prevent SQL injection attacks.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php